# I receive object empty in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, fetch, postman

I receive object empty, when i send data with fetch, but with postman i have the data, I dont know, why this happend?

This is my code in the frontend.

```
let formReset = document.querySelector('#reset-form')
    let email = document.querySelector("input[name='email']")
    let url = 'http://localhost:3000'
    var misCabeceras = new Headers();


    formReset.addEventListener('submit', (e)=>{
        let data = {
            email: email.value
        }
        fetch(url+'/forget-password', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers:misCabeceras,
            mode: 'cors'
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => data)
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
        e.preventDefault()
    })
```

In nodejs this:

```
 router.post("/forget-password",(req,res)=>{
        console.log(req.body)
    })
```

Image in postman
[image]

If i send data with the browser in the header i received the data but in my console or node is empty :/, is my first time with nodejs

[image]

Comment: In the screenshot from the browser, you are looking at the request, not the response. What appears when you click on `Response`? Also, what appears in the console tab?

Comment: in response i dont have answer, because i dont comeback the data e.e, I only write console.log(req.body) to see the data in nodejs.

Comment: Do you have a body-parser middleware in place?

Comment: @SándorBakos yes i have body-parser, but i delete the body-parser and I send data with postman and found, I receive the data, but in the browser no :/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the missing comma in the fetch object, as shown below:

```
fetch(url+'/forget-password', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: misCabeceras,
  mode: 'cors',
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
}
```

Comment: In the code sample you provide there is no comma following `'cors'`, which will cause an error. Since Postman is working, the problem must be in your frontend code.

Comment: I delete the last code and i want the next code, in the console the browser show the json but in nodejs i receive the data empty. fetch('http://localhost:3000/forget-password', {
   method: 'POST',
   body: JSON.stringify({user:email.value})
  }).then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => data)
  .catch(err => console.log(err))

Comment: I don't know what your previous comment means.

Comment: I delete the last code, and I write the next code       
          fetch('http://localhost:3000/forget-password', {
   method: 'POST',
   body: JSON.stringify({user:email.value})
  }).then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => data)
  .catch(err => console.log(err)) but i have the same result :/

Comment: You should not delete the `headers` and `mode` key-value pairs.

Comment: I delete the headers and mode, but is the same result.....